# Unable to run vlc-android on simulator/device

Tags: android-studio, vlc-android

I am following the below url link to compile and run vlc-android

https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/

I can create the apk via "Generate Signed APK" from Android Studio.

But when I want to run it on the simulator or a connected device I get the following error.

Error log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:vlc-android:assembleChromeARMv5Debug]
:libvlc:buildDebugARMv5
For an ARMv6 device without FPU:
use "-a armeabi-nofpu"
For an ARMv5 device:
use "-a armeabi-v5"
ABI:        armeabi
API:        android-9
SYSROOT:    /Users/ashishkumarpatel/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
FPU:        NO
ARMv5:       YES
PATH:       /Users/ashishkumarpatel/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
CFLAGS:            -g -O2 -fstrict-aliasing -funsafe-math-optimizations -mlong-calls
EXTRA_CFLAGS:      -march=armv5te -mtune=arm9tdmi -msoft-float -I/Users/ashishkumarpatel/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -I/Users/ashishkumarpatel/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/include
./compile-libvlc.sh: line 413: cd: vlc: No such file or directory
Building tools
./compile-libvlc.sh: line 421: cd: extras/tools: No such file or directory
./compile-libvlc.sh: line 422: ./bootstrap: No such file or directory
buildsystem tools: bootstrap failed
:libvlc:buildDebugARMv5 FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':libvlc:buildDebugARMv5'.
```

Error message:

```
Process 'command './compile-libvlc.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.162 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: I think this is the first point of error - `./compile-libvlc.sh: line 413: cd: vlc: No such file or directory` You can view that script `compile-libvlc.sh` and detct why vlc folder was not found.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I checked but I did not find mkdir vlc and there is no other clue :(